# Error opening data file ./eng.traineddata

Tags: java, image

I was going to read text from a PNG file, I used this code but I got this error, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

GIT - https://github.com/csanuragjain/extra/tree/master/ReadFromImages

```
Error opening data file ./eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fdc520d3c27, pid=19781, tid=0x00007fdcae2c5700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_271-b09) (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.271-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libtesseract.so.4+0xa1c27]  tesseract::Tesseract::recog_all_words(PAGE_RES*, ETEXT_DESC*, TBOX const*, char const*, int)+0x437
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/bhanuka/Documents/CodeByB/Repos/imagereader/hs_err_pid19781.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Comment: The language file's probably corrupted. Try grabbing another and using it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution,

I get the **tesseract** package

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-eng
```

and added below lines to my Java code

```
Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
tesseract.setDatapath("/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata");
```